# Does every deep-q net needs a terminal state?

Tags: tensorflow

does every deep-q network needs a terminal state like in the atari games ? So that the network sees an end ? Or is it used to punish it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

A terminal state is not required, but it is useful and is not used just for punishment.

To take Pong as example the terminal state is triggered whenever a player scores or concedes. It is punishment neutral. The point of terminal state here is because after scoring the game state is reset, the ball and paddles are moved back to the starting positions. This means there is no connection between the previous state(the terminal one) and the next state. When computing the reward for any none terminal state we use the reward in that state plus the Q-functions expected future reward. In a terminal state there is no future reward so you can just use the reward from the current state.

The advantage of this is it massively reduces noise when learning. As I said you do not need a terminal state, but if you don't have one you may want to adjust your future reward discount down quite a bit lower than the standard 0.99 because at this level most rewards will eventually blend together over time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @DanielSlater for your answer. I decreased the future-reward-discount already to 0.9, but i will play  more around with it, to see what happens.    Another question: Does the reward needs to increase, or could i reward it, e.g. always with 1 point when it reaches a goal, then send a new goal, and when it reaches again this goal, give again only 1 point, not 2 points ? Or do i need to increase the reward 0,1,2,3... and so on ?

Comment: @floboticsrobotics reward does not need to increase. But you may want some rewards to be larger than others. Reward is about relative value you want the agent to attach to different states. From what you say, you want your agent to go to each goal in turn, so 1 for each may be sufficient(though only testing can really tell you).